# Backbone.js View, ParentView, Model, Collection and Template Best Practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am looking for some description of best practices for views and models/collections in Backbone. I know how to add models to collections, render views using templates and use views in parent views, however I'm looking for more context and perhaps some example links.

**I've updated this question to be more specific.**

Let's say you have a more grid layout with all kinds of variation, that gets pulled from the same collection. What would you do here to create this page? A simple child view repeated in a parent view won't work because the variation of the grid items is too great. Do you:

- create tons of tiny views and collections and render all of these different views using the relevant collections into that one page?
- create a complex template file that has a loop in it, that as you go through the loop, the loop outputs different markup?
- Do people put multiple views inside a parent view, all from the same model?

Similarly, do people mix different models into the same parent view? For example movies and tv shows - these different models, can get they added to the same collection that renders that list?

Thanks!

Comment: Re: "Could you not just have a template that has logic in it and loop through the collection in your view", what piece of code would own that template? What piece of code would be responsible for responding to `"add"` or `"remove"` events from the collection? And a parent view is certainly allowed to tell its children what template to use or similarly, to put its children into containers that the parent controls and those containers can position and size themselves however they want. Perhaps a more concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, I think your examples do shed some light on the template bit. I guess the example is a webpage where you have blocks of content that all come from the same model, but are displayed differently. The important bit is they are displayed in these templates in a specific order. So featured area first, etc. How do you structure that view? Parent view with multiple different types of children views? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked good question. To answer it lets take a look to this from other angle:

On my exp i used to check first is there any logic on parent view, like sorting, validation, search and so on. Second - Collection with models or just model with array as property : is the model is independent and may exist without collection , for example you have navigation item, and there are no sense to make separate model for each item and navigation as collection as you will never use item itself. Another case you have user list. You may use user model in a lot of places and its better to make a separate model for user and collection to combine it.

Your case with UL may be resolved with single model and `items` properties with array of `li`, simple grid may have same approach as i don't see some special logic on wrap from your description.

But i should point out - i had close task to build mansory grid with collection parsed from server, items were models as it had different data structure, different templates and different events listener.

Taking decision i considered folowing:

- item as independent tile, may be used as in grid and also independent.
- item is model + template + view. different Models types helped to support different data structure, different Views types helped to support different events listeners and user interaction, different templates - diff looks.
- collection as a tool to fetch initial data + load extra items + arrange mansonry view + create models according to fetched result.

**UPDATE**

Lets consider this pseudo code as masnonry implementation:

Models may looks like these:

```
var MansonryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        /* Common methods and properties */
    }),

    MansonryVideoModel = MansonryModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            type: 'video',
            videoUrl: '#',
            thumbnail: 'no-cover.jpg'
        }
    }),

    MansonryImageModel = MansonryModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            type: 'image',
            pictureUrl: '#',
            alt: 'no-pictire'
        }
    });

var MansonryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MansonryModel
});
```

Views could be like this:

```
var MansonryTileView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        /* place to keep some common methods and properties */
    }),

    MansonryVideoTile = MansonryTileView.extend({
        template: '#video-tile',
        events: {
            'click .play': 'playVideo'
        },
        playVideo: function(){}
    }),

    MansonryImageTile = MansonryTileView.extend({
        template: '#image-tile',
        events: {
            'click .enlarge': 'enlargePicture'
        },
        enlargePicture: function(){}
    });

var MansonryListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView : MansonryItem
})
```

Hope this help

Comment: Your answer touches on the things I'm interested in. I'd love more detail if you have any. So, from the start - If the parent view has no logic, you don't make one? Now, for the bigger issue - if you have a grid list (like Masonry you mention): if you have different layouts of the grid items (like an extra div inside), what do you do here? Do you have multiple child views? Or do you have template logic?

Comment: If parent view has no logic and there is no need to use collection - i use ItemView + Model. If take as an example navigation it will be NavigationModel with property items + NavigationView with iteration over this array. So there will be only one View with template you need. Second, about mansonry, make sense to use some base view as parent for all types and extend it with custom template and events listener + here is necessary to use parent view as you need to delegate it building mansonry layout, because single tile cant do it

Comment: Ok - so do people use a base parent view with multiple child views, then? And somehow use different child views for each of the grid items? What about different different models? Are there any examples of this around?

Comment: please checkout answer update. BaseView is a 'prototype' for all other items views, same structure for models